# undefined method `name' for 376.5:Float en rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy intentando armar una clase de instancia llamada @rooms, que alberga los datos de 2 tabla una de room, que son los datos de la piezas y un dato de reserva, que es el total, que representa el total del arriendo de la pieza.

lo que hice es recorrer y hacer un array con los datos que ingreso, a través del siguiente método

```
  def selected_room
    @roomsel = []
    @items.each do |item|
      @roomsel << Room.find(item.room_id)
      @roomsel << ItemReservation.find_by(room_id: item.room_id).total
    end
    return @roomsel  
  end
```

La pregunta es como puedo armar para incluir el total al array de room para que cuando llame a @room o cualquier clase de instancia  desde view pueda obtener el dato que deseo por ejemplo @room.total y pueda ver cada una de las piezas tenga el total y sus datos, al visualizar el view me aparece el erro undefined method 'name' for 376,5 float, que es el primer valor de total.

No se que si se entiende pero me gustaría su ayuda Gracias se lo agradezco

Copio el código del view

```
  <br/> Habitaciones: <br/>
  <% @rooms.each do |rm|%>
  <div clase= "row">
    <div class= "col-sm-12">
      <h4><%= rm.name %></h4>
      <small"> Precio:$ <%= rm.price %> </small>
      <ul>
        <li>
          Metros : <%= rm.meter %>
        </li>
        <li>
          Tipo de Cama: <%= rm.type_bed %>
        </li>
        <li>
          Nº de cama: <%= rm.num_bed %>
        </li>
        <li>
          Descripcion: <%= rm.comment %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class= "col-sm-12 ">
      <div class="row container-fluid">
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img == "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img2== "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img2, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img3 == "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img3, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-12 col-md-3 text-center">
          <% if rm.img4 == "" %>
            <%= image_tag "Motorhotel.png", class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% else %>
            <%= img_tag rm.img4, class: "Logo img-fluid", alt: 'Motor Hotelero GO ' %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <%end%>
```

modelos
Room

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client
  
  has_many :item_reservations, through: :reservations

end
```

ItemReservation

```
class ItemReservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :reservation

end
```

Reservation

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :client

  has_many :user_reservation
  has_many :other_reservation
  has_many :obs_reservation
  has_many :item_reservations, through: :rooms

end
```

Comment: El error de seguro te lo arroja `rm.name` porque en `@roomsel << ItemReservation.find_by(room_id: item.room_id).total` estás agregando un número en vez de la instancia de un modelo. ¿puedes agregar a tu pregunta el código de cómo se relacionan los modelos de items, rooms e item_reservations?

Comment: Además, de los campos `rm.xxxx` que tienes en la vista, ¿todos pertenecen a rooms o a qué modelo pertenece c/u?

Comment: hola Alter Lagos te comento me agrega los n elementos, en este caso 2

Comment: Te lo agregue los modelos Gracias

Comment: No entiendo como están relacionados tus modelos. room tiene `has_many :item_reservations, through: :reservations`, pero no veo `reservations` definido en room, luego reservation tiene `has_many :item_reservations, through: :rooms` (que tampoco tiene definido rooms), pero esto entraría en conflicto con la definición de item_reservations en room, entraría en un loop de dependencia o algo por el estilo, tampoco me contaste a qué modelo pertenece cada uno de los campos que quieres mostrar.

Comment: Estimado este es mi primer sistema en Rails, así k errores debe a ver

Comment: Según el bootcamp con la palabra through se integra reservation en room, ya que es una relación n a n, dime qué si está bien o no ??, Necesito extraer todo los campos de rooms y solo total en ítems reservation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas creando un array con un objeto Room en los elementos impares y el total en los pares

Yo meteria un hash con los dos elementos en ese array

```
def selected_room
  @roomsel = @items.map do |item|
   {
    room: Room.find(item.room_id),
    total: ItemReservation.find_by(room_id: item.room_id).total
   }
  end
end
```

En la vista tienes que indicar el indice rm[:room].name por ejemplo para sacar el nombre y rm[:total] para el precio